# Xamarin DataGrid Header Vertically down

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, datagrid

does anyone know whether is it possible to change the header to by row instead of column? Currently it look like this 
[image]

code

```
<dg:DataGrid HeaderHeight="50"
     BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8">
<dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 1"/>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 2"/>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 3"/>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 4"/>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 5"/>
    <dg:DataGridColumn Title="Zone 6"/>
</dg:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I want it to be

[image]

I tried removing the header and just append header title as rows in my viewmodel class. It works but requires more work to do. Just wondering if there is any other way of achieving this result?

Comment: Post your xaml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin **DataGrid** doesn't support such a feature .

**Option 1:**

You could use the library [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid/#show-github-usage) from nuget . The [docs](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started?utm_source=nuget&utm_medium=listing) is available and you can  your free license for our complete product offering by signing in with LinkedIn or XING. Check https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense?utm_source=nuget&utm_medium=listing .

**Option 2:**

Actually , you could implement such a layout by using **BindableLayout**

#### in xaml

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <Frame Padding="0" Margin="{Binding Margin}">
                    <Grid RowSpacing="0.1" ColumnSpacing="0">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"  />

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0" BorderColor="Black" >

                            <Label BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                        </Frame>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0" BorderColor="Black" >

                            <Label  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Win}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                        </Frame>



                        <Frame BackgroundColor="{Binding BgColor}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,0" BorderColor="Black" >

                            <Label Text="{Binding Home}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

                        </Frame>



                    </Grid>
                </Frame>


            </DataTemplate>

        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>



    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

#### in Code Behind

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Teams = new ObservableCollection<Team>();

        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "Zone2", Win = "Zone3", Name = "Zone1", Margin = new Thickness(0,0,-10,0),BgColor=Color.LightGray }); ;
        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "333", Win = "222", Name = "111", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -10, 0), BgColor = Color.White });
        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "333", Win = "222", Name = "111", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -10, 0), BgColor = Color.White });
        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "333", Win = "222", Name = "111", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -10, 0), BgColor = Color.White });
        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "333", Win = "222", Name = "111", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, -10, 0), BgColor = Color.White });
        Teams.Add(new Team() { Home = "444", Win = "555", Name = "666", Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), BgColor = Color.White });

    }
}


public class Team
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Win { get; set; }
    public string Loose { get; set; }
    public string Home { get; set; }
    public string Percentage { get; set; }
    public Color BgColor { get; set; }
    public Thickness Margin { get; set; }

}
```

[image]